# Session preservation

Tags: php, jquery, session

I read all other question but nothing really helped.

I have one page with display and other php files supporting it but when I pass a POST and make a $_SESSION['view'] out of it with another POST request but not same one the $_SESSION['view'] is gone.

So in practic when user change view from four months (default) to one month and then click NEXT view gets back to four months.

Display Page

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $dateb = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
    $_SESSION['usrdate'] = $dateb;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
        <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link href="site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#four").click(function () {
                        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "switcher.php",
                            data: {
                                view: "four"
                            },
                            success: function (html) {

                                $("#loadplace").html(html);

                            }
                        });
                        return jqXHR.responseText;
                    });
                    $("#one").click(function () {
                        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "switcher.php",
                            data: {
                                view: "one"
                            },
                            success: function (html) {

                                $("#loadplace").html(html);

                            }
                        });
                        return jqXHR.responseText;
                    });
                    $("#next").click(function () {
                        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "switcher.php",
                            data: {
                                toggle: "next"
                            },
                            success: function (html) {

                                $("#loadplace").html(html);

                            }
                        });
                        return jqXHR.responseText;
                    });

                });
    </script>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="loginform"><?php


    /*require "navigation.php";*/
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        include "logon.php";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='logoff.php'>Logout</a>";
    }

    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="loadplace">
    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    include "switcher.php";
    }
    ?>
    </div>

    <div id="tog"><button type="button" id="prev">Prev</button>
    <button type="button" id="next">Next</button></div><br/><br/>
            <div id="view"><button type="button" id="four">Four</button>
    <button type="button" id="one">One</button></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Script

```
<?php
    session_start();
$_SESSION['view'] =  $_POST["view"];
$_SESSION['toggle']= $_POST["toggle"];
$tog = $_SESSION["toggle"];



if ($_SESSION['view'] == "four") {
    include_once "four_m.php";
} elseif ($_SESSION['view'] == "one") {
    include "calendar.php";
} elseif ($_SESSION['view'] == "week") {
    include "week.php";
} elseif ($_SESSION['view'] == "day") {
    include "day.php";
} else {
    include "four_m.php";
}

?>
```

Comment: because you keep overwriting it

Comment: Any idea how to not overwrite it?

Comment: Your code works for me. Although I don't have switcher.php so I did a simple $_SESSION['view'] check to make sure the value remains the same. It did. And I'm assuming the PHP code you provided is ses.php. What is your switcher.php code?

Comment: My bad, I tried to save those values in mysql but I need to do everything without page refresh and I left ses.php instead of switcher.php. But still problem is unsolved. Maybe something is wrong with my php.ini?

Comment: Solution was so simple and still took me few hours. Simple if statement with isset to not overwrite it.